# $T$ Aronszajn tree on $\omega_1$ - partition of $T$ into countably-many antichains.

Tags: set-theory, filters

I encountered this exercice on trees :

> Suppose $T$ is an Aronszajn tree on $\omega_1$. Find a partial ordering $\mathbb{P}$ and a family $\mathcal{F}=\{D_\alpha:\alpha<\omega_1\}$ dense subsets of $\mathbb{P}$ such that if $G$ is $\mathcal{F}$-generic, then $\bigcup G : T\to\omega$ is such that the preimage of each $n$ is an antichain of $T$, i.e., $G$ yields a partition of $T$ into countably-many antichains.

I would appreciate someone opinion on my line of thoughts:

First, I need to find a poset $\mathbb{P}$, and a family $\cal F$ such that if a there is $G$ $\cal F$-generic, then $T$ is special. So $\mathbb{P}$ must be closely related to $T$. why not take $T$ itself then?

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the family of all maximal antichain of $\mathbb{P}$, and for any $A\in\mathcal{A}$, let
$$ D_A =\{ p, \ p\leq q \text{ for some }q\in A\}$$ 
We know that for any maximal antichain $A$, $D_A$ is dense open. Therefore we define
$$ \mathcal{F} = \{ D_A, \ A\in\mathcal{A}\}$$

Now suppose we have $G$, $\mathcal{F}$-generic. Then $G$ intersect each $D_A$. I feel that I'm getting close, but I can't conclude. Any help?

Comment: This process is called *specialization*, and if $T$ satisfies this partition it is *special*. There are always special Aronszajn trees, but it's not provable that there are non-special ones (on $\omega_1$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is the wrong way to think about it, since the generic subset won't code a function from $T$ to $\omega$.  Because we're trying to approximate a function from $T$ to $\omega$ (with some special properties), the natural poset to use is just finite approximations to such a function.

In particular, we can take $\mathbb{P}$ to be the set of finite partial functions from $T$ to $\omega$ such that the pre-images of each $n\in\omega$ are antichains.  And as usual for functions, we can order them by reverse inclusion: $p\leqslant q\in\mathbb{P}$ iff $p\supseteq q$.

To ensure the generic $G$ codes a function $\bigcup G$ defined on all of $T$, have $D_t$ basically state "$t$ in in my domain".  Explicitly, you can consider $D_t= \{ p\in\mathbb{P}:t\in\mathrm{dom}(p) \} \text{.}$
It's not difficult to show that each $D_t$ is dense in $T$, and the preimages of $\bigcup G$ of each $n\in\omega$ still remain antichains.

Comment: Not sure to see why the pre-images of $\bigcup G$ are still antichain. I guess I need to use the fact that $T$ is an Aronszajn tree on $\omega_1$ as I have not used it yet. 

I would reason by contradiction. assuming there are two compatible elements $t_1,t_2$ of $T$, such that $\bigcup G(t_1)=\bigcup G(t_2)=n$. Then as the preimage of each element of $\mathbb{P}$ are antichain, this means that there are two function $p,q\in G$ such that $p(t_1)=q(t_2)=n\ldots$ Now I should try to build a $\omega_1$ branch from this to get a contradiction.

Comment: @ThomasLesgourgues You should think more about the properties of $G$.  If $\bigcup G(t_1)=\bigcup G(t_2)=n$, then there are elements $p\in G$ and $q\in G$ where $p(t_1)=n$ and $q(t_2)=n$.  But note that $G$ is a _filter_.  So there is some common extension $r\in\mathbb{P}$, $r\leqslant p$, $r\leqslant q$ (which is a problem by definition of $\mathbb{P}$ and $\leqslant$).

Comment: I think I'm missing a key notion here. Why can we ensure that there is a common extension $r$? If there is some $t_3\in T$ in dom($p$) and in dom($q$), with $p(t_3)\neq q(t_3)$, then we cannot find a common extension. Thanks for the help, this domain of mathematic is quite new for me. I'm surprised that we never used the Aronszajn property of $T$, so far this is true for any tree no?

Comment: @ThomasLesgourgues If $p$ and $q$ disagreed somwhere, then they couldn't both be in the filter (precisely because there is no common extension).  I suggest reading up a bit on [filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(mathematics)#General_definition).

Comment: Also, you're right that the Aronszajn property doesn't come into play for getting such a function.  But it impacts properties of the poset $\mathbb{P}$.  In particular, $\mathbb{P}$ is ccc, and so won't collapse any cardinals.

Comment: Thanks, I got mixed up between general filters definition, and filters on set, where condition 2 is replace by $X,Y \in F \Rightarrow X\cap Y\in F$. They might be equivalent, but yeah the generic filter implies that any two elements are compatible.